# Blender to unity fix armature deform super problem

Tags: armature, bones, unity, quaternion

I have a super problem trying to port a created mod in blender to unity,  the mod was done using a game template (cityskilines citizen armature template). I bind my model to armature, transfer and repainted wieghts, ok. Fix rotation issues by rotation trick  unity to blender in order to fix import position in unity , location rotation mesh and armature are zero. Also clear bones roll in  order to prevent several weird bone rotations from armature template and I'm ready with the fbx I exported to unity in order to test positions. however despite to work well in unity, when rotate bones.

When I try to import that fbx in to city skilines games assets creator my armature is deformed and mesh is destroyed. any idea what could be if the problem is armature, bones, quaternions to euler or yet something else? iIadd an image to show the problem, hope for an expert's help.[image: test]

Comment: Man, no stream of consciousness please.

Comment: problem solved, thanks to blender power, key was on armature rotations, after fix that it worked. a great step for blender, is supposed that only way to port mods was with  maya . now maya is useless.